# Overfitting if estimating multiple target parameters in dataset (avoiding Table 2 Fallacy)?

Tags: regression-coefficients, overfitting, treatment-effect, causal-diagram, fallacy

For my job I'm sometimes asked to find the driving factors behind a healthcare outcome such as total annual cost or # of inpatient visits.

"Driving factors" typically means reporting average effects for various variables (age, sex, socioeconomic factors, medical diagnoses) estimated from linear regression or GLM coefficients.

However, I see this approach runs the risk of biased estimates due to the [Table 2 Fallacy](https://academic.oup.com/aje/article/177/4/292/147738?login=false).

A better strategy seems to be:

1. Build a causal diagram (directed acyclic graph) representing the cause-effect relationships between the explanatory variables (which may include a treatment or intervention) and the outcome,
2. Run $p$ separate multiple regressions (or other models) with the variables $x_1,x_2,...,x_p$ selected as the primary exposure of each regression, including other variables as appropriate based on the DAG,
3. Report the average effect for each $x_i$ as the primary exposure.

This does mean performing $p$ models on the same data (albeit focusing on a different exposure variable each time).

Do we run the risk of overfitting?